# Convert jintarray to jfloatarray Android JNI

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

I would like to know what is the right way to convert jintarray to jfloatarray?

This is how I tried to convert it but it doesn't work properly:

```
JNIEXPORT jdouble JNICALL Java_com_MES_yo_NativeClass_CalcSumDiff(JNIEnv * env, jclass cls,jintArray intarray1,  jintArray intarray2, jint ColsCount, jint RowsCount)
        {


            jboolean ji1,ji2;
            jdouble Result = 0;
            float * inputarray1 = env->GetFloatArrayElements((jfloatArray)intarray1,&ji1);
            float * inputarray2 = env->GetFloatArrayElements((jfloatArray)intarray2,&ji2);

            int sum  = 0;
            for(int i = 0 ; i < (RowsCount * ColsCount) - 1; i++)
            {
                sum += abs((pow(inputarray1[i], 1.5)/ 15.96871942) - (pow(inputarray2[i],1.5)/15.96871942));
/*              __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "My Error", "inputarray1[i] = %d" ,inputarray1[i]);
                __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "My Error", "inputarray2[i] = %d" ,inputarray2[i]);
                __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "My Error", "sum = %d" ,sum);*/
            }

            env->ReleaseFloatArrayElements((jfloatArray)intarray1, inputarray1,0);
            env->ReleaseFloatArrayElements((jfloatArray)intarray2, inputarray2,0);
            return sum;
        }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot magically cast jintArray to jFLoatArray, but you can perform all your calculations with integer inputs:

```
JNIEXPORT jdouble JNICALL Java_com_MES_yo_NativeClass_CalcSumDiff(JNIEnv * env, jclass cls,jintArray intarray1,  jintArray intarray2, jint ColsCount, jint RowsCount)
{
    jboolean ji1,ji2;
    jdouble Result = 0;
    int * inputarray1 = env->GetIntArrayElements(intarray1,&ji1);
    int * inputarray2 = env->GetIntArrayElements(intarray2,&ji2);

    double sum  = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < (RowsCount * ColsCount) - 1; i++)
    {
        sum += abs((pow(inputarray1[i], 1.5)/ 15.96871942) - (pow(inputarray2[i],1.5)/15.96871942));
/*              __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "My Error", "inputarray1[i] = %d" ,inputarray1[i]);
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "My Error", "inputarray2[i] = %d" ,inputarray2[i]);
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "My Error", "sum = %d" ,sum);*/
    }

    env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(intarray1, inputarray1,0);
    env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(intarray2, inputarray2,0);
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: But then all the parameters are integers and not floats

Comment: Which parameters? `pow(int, double)` produces **double**, and `sum` is also **double** (*NB:* fixed). Or if the actual parameters are float arrays, you must change the function declaration: `JNIEXPORT jdouble JNICALL Java_com_MES_yo_NativeClass_CalcSumDiff(JNIEnv * env, jclass cls, jfloatArray array1,  jfloatArray array2, jint ColsCount, jint RowsCount)`

Comment: Note that your loop is probably wrong; why would you skip the last element in the arrays (`inputarray1[RowsCount*ColsCount-1]`)? Also, you don't need to pass the dimensions if all you need is scan of the whole array: you can simply write `for (int i=0; i<env->GetArrayLength(intarray1); i++)`